# Implementing Voice navigation in HERE maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I am building a map-based app in iOS (Objective-C) using HERE maps, and am new to this. I was successful in implementing navigation but I am facing a hitch in implementing voice instruction for navigation. This is the code that I have:

```
- (void) beginNavigationMethod {
    self.mapView.zoomLevel = 17.0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didUpdatePositionForNavigation) name:NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePositionNotification object:[NMAPositioningManager sharedPositioningManager]];

    NMAVoiceCatalog *voiceCatalog = [NMAVoiceCatalog sharedVoiceCatalog];
    voiceCatalog.delegate = self;
    [voiceCatalog updateVoiceCatalog];

    [self.navigationManager startTurnByTurnNavigationWithRoute:self.route];
    [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingEnabled = YES;
    [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingAutoZoomEnabled = YES;
    [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingOrientation
    = NMAMapTrackingOrientationDynamic;
    [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].speedWarningEnabled = YES;
    NSError* error = [[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager] startTurnByTurnNavigationWithRoute:self.route];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

- (void)voiceCatalog:(nonnull NMAVoiceCatalog *)voiceCatalog didUpdateWithError:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateWithError: %@",error);
}
```

I basically don't know how to proceed with this. My apologies for being so naive. If anyone could guide me through this, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at docs: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/map-voice-instructions.html

Otherwise, where is an example for Android: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/36#issuecomment-304873154, if you can go through it it will give you an impression of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the links but I have checked the first link already, could you please help me with code in Objective - C.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
 [[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager] setVoicePackageMeasurementSystem:NMAMeasurementSystemImperialUS];
 [[NMAAudioManager sharedAudioManager] setDelegate:self];
 [[NMAAudioManager sharedAudioManager]setManagesAudioSession:NO];
```

Here Map Delegate Method

```
 - (BOOL)audioManager:(NMAAudioManager *)audioManager shouldPlayOutput:(NMAAudioOutput *)output{  
       return true;
   }
```

Project Setting->General->Capabilities->Background Modes

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help I am not sure what happened but I just used the code from their demo project and it started working.